# Неправильная раздача статики через nginx

Tags: nginx, static

Не получается правильно настроить раздачу статики через nginx.

Часть конфига (не обращайте внимание на непонятные теги - это на самом деле шаблон конфига, но это неважно)

```
# --request routing--
    server {
        server_name  _;
        listen       <%= ENV['PORT'] %>;
        port_in_redirect off;   
        autoindex        off;
        
        root   /app/assets;
        
        location = / {
            root   /app/assets;
            index  index.html;
            expires 1d;
        }
        
        location /api {
            alias   /app/doc;
            index  index.html;
            expires 1d;
        }
      
        location /api/v1/ {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:<%= ENV['APP_PORT'] %>; 
            #proxy_pass http://app_server;
            #proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            
            #proxy_connect_timeout      60s; # default
            #proxy_send_timeout         60s; # default
            #proxy_read_timeout         60s; # default
            
            #proxy_buffer_size          4k;
            #proxy_buffers              4 32k;
            #proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
            #proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
            
            
            
            #limit_conn conn_per_ip 10;  # 10 соединений с одного IP
            #limit_conn conn_per_server 100;  # 100 соединений для всего сервера
            limit_req zone=req_per_ip burst=15 nodelay; # не больше 15 запросов превышающих лимит
        }

...
```

Вот результат:

https://fasttranslator2.herokuapp.com

А  вот как должно быть (раздача статики моим Go-приложением):

https://fasttranslator.herokuapp.com

P.S. ПО факту получается, что не применяются стили. Хотя сам файл style.css не вызывает 404 ошибки. Лог роутера на хостинге heroku:
2021-02-02T13:34:54.143307+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/style.css" status=200 bytes=771 protocol=https

Comment: Обе страницы выглядят полностью одинаково и не вызывают никаких ошибок. В чём проблема-то?

Comment: Прошу извинения.  Когда написал вопрос - внезапно дошло почему не работало: строчка  include       mime.types; была почему-то закомментирована  в конфиге. Перезалил сайт - и стало все как надо.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в закомментированной строчке конфига:
include mime.types;